# IONIC4 When we go one page to another and comeback showing blank page in ios

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

When we comeback same page using back button, automatically ionViewDidLoad() method will trigger in the back page(starting page). In that, I used service call and I'm getting data(List) as well. But, showing black page in ios and if we click or long touch on any button on the screen,then data showing.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Try to use ionViewWillEnter() , maybe its because the page is already load beforeyou load your list.